# Gradle/Java: How to upgrade log4j safely?

Tags: java, security, gradle, logging

Given the recent Log4J [vulnerability](https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/detail/CVE-2021-44228)
what is the safest way to upgrade transitive dependencies in a gradle project? My project doesn't explicitly use log4j(it uses logback) but it has a number of dependencies that brings in the vulnerable versions(< 2.15.0). First, is it necessary to upgrade anything if my SLF4J uses logback? And if I were to upgrade, how do I force 2.15 to be present in classpath instead of the older version?

Comment: Welcome!  If you were to edit your post to clarify what you're trying to do, and where your problem is, then it would help others help you figure it out.  Also, check out "[ask]" and how to create a [mcve].

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Add the following to your `gradle.build` file:

```
configurations.all {
  resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { details ->
    if (details.requested.group == 'org.apache.logging.log4j') {
      details.useVersion '2.21.1'
      details.because 'zero-day exploits suck'
    }
  }
}

dependencies {
…
}
```

Note that as the [documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/resolution_rules.html#sec:dependency_resolve_rules) points out:

> the following mechanisms allow you to write rules which are directly
> injected into the resolution engine. Because of this, they can be seen
> as *brute force* solutions, that may hide future problems (e.g. if new
> dependencies are added). Therefore, the general advice is to only use
> the following mechanisms if other means are not sufficient.

I realize the OP asks for the "safest" way to upgrade dependencies -- I choose to interpret that as most-likely to remove zero-day exploits. Nevertheless, I do recognize that this brute force approach doesn't guarantee compatibility between libraries, but this should make sure no vulnerable versions of log4j end up in your dependency tree / builds.

You should of course run `gradle dependencies` after you make the change to be sure the changes took and you don't have any lingering versions with issues.

***Update:*** removed the version comparison, as recommended [here](https://spring.io/blog/2021/12/10/log4j2-vulnerability-and-spring-boot).

***Update:*** increased version to 2.21.1

Comment: **Potentially important:** consider `<= '2.15.0'`, not `<`. Running `./gradlew dependencies` with just `<` in the configuration gave me a dependency tree output including `org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-1.2-api -> 2.15.0` and its child dependency `org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:2.15.0 -> ` **`2.11.2`**. With `<=` I got `org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-1.2-api -> 2.15.0`
and `org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:2.15.0`.

Comment: **Update** Actually after looking into it a bit further I think the better change is to `&& details.target.version < '2.15.0'` — then we shouldn’t accidentally downgrade when there's a conflict. I am unsure if we should also change to `details.target.group` or not.

Comment: The kotlin version is :


configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.eachDependency {
        if (requested.group == "org.apache.logging.log4j") {
            useVersion("2.17.0")
            because("zero-day-exploits suck")
        }
    }
}

Comment: You may also need to explicitly exclude the old log4j package if it comes in as a transitive dependency: ```configurations{
    runtime.exclude group: "log4j", module: "log4j"
}``` you would need to test to be 100% sure this did not break anything in your project

Answer (score 0):

You can add Dependency Management plugin to your gradle.build:

```
plugins {
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.11.RELEASE'
}

dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom 'org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-bom:2.17.0'
    }
}
```

To confirm the change, run
`./gradlew dependencies`
you should see something like

```
 +--- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-to-slf4j:2.14.1 -> 2.17.0
|    |    |    |    +--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.25 -> 1.7.32
|    |    |    |    \--- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:2.17.0
```